# How to define a play route to pass an int[] param to the action

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I am new to Java, Playframework and Scala.  I am trying to create a route to my action using an array, but am getting an error.  I know the error says to use a custom query binder, but I also found spots that refer to this being supported in play 2.1.  I am using 2.2.1.  Is there something that I am missing, or do I need to create a custom QueryStringBinder?  Is there a better way to do this?

Route -

`GET /someAction controllers.MyController.someAction(employees:Array[Int])`

Controller Action -

`public static Result someAction(Array<int> employees) 
{
    ...
}`

Error :

No QueryString binder found for type Array[Int]. Try to implement an implicit QueryStringBindable for this type.

Comment: What do you want to pass as employees Array?

Comment: Looking simply to pass an array of ints.

Comment: I know I can pass a string, parse it into an array and convert to int.  But that doesn't keep my controller action clean.  I would prefer to be explicit about what my controller is expecting.

Comment: Actually, I have seen opinions that it's better to pass a whole String. Either way, here is what I've found [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/c5kB6wmcF8Q)